# C# выдает ошибку при работе с EXCEL файлом

Tags: c#, excel, interop

установлен Microsoft Office профессиональный плюс 2010, пробую работать с Excel файлами, на этапе открытия файла (на строке `Excel.Workbook Book = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/NordeN/Desktop/1.xlsx");`) выдает следующую ошибку:

`System.InvalidCastException: "Невозможно привести COM-объект типа "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass" к интерфейсному типу "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application". Операция завершилась со сбоем, поскольку вызов QueryInterface COM-компонента для интерфейса с IID "{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" возвратил следующую ошибку: Библиотека не зарегистрирована. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))."`

В референсы проекта добавлены Microsoft.Office.Core и Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Для меня критично, чтобы программа работала именно из под этой версии офиса. Подскажите как решить проблему, пробовал добавить в проект ссылку на исполняемый файл EXCEL, тоже не помогло.

Comment: Библиотека не зарегистрирована.  Зарегистрировать её нужно.

Comment: Ссылку не дадите где почитать об этом?

Comment: Поставьте офис посвежее. Лет хотя-бы на 6. И пересоздайте референсы.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть обращение к Excel.Application

```
// Объявление приложения
Excel.Application ex = new Excel.Application();

// Открытие книги (файла)
ex.Workbooks.Open(dlg.FileName);

// Получение первой книги
Excel.Workbooks books = (Excel.Workbooks)ex.Workbooks;
Excel.Workbook book = (Excel.Workbook)(books.get_Item(1));

// Получение первой страницы
Excel.Sheets sheets = (Excel.Sheets)book.Worksheets;
Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)(sheets.get_Item(1));
```